# What is the difference between "jaunt" and "excursion", "trip" and "outing"? Can we say "secretive outing" or "secretive absence"?

Tags: word-choice

I found the following sentence in today's New York Times. Apparently, *secretive jaunt* of New York Mayor Michael R. Bloomberg sounds to carry some speculations. And for a foreign English learner like me, *jaunt* seems to be a 'less well-worn' word (Is this expression right?). What is the difference of meaning among *jaunt*, *excursion*, *outing*, *trip*, and *journey*?

> **Mayoral Sign-Out Sheet?** Secretive Jaunts Spur a Thought: Angered by Mayor Michael R. Bloomberg's refusal to say where he was during the December blizzard, lawmakers may consider requiring mayors to acknowledge absences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [jaunt](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jaunt) is

> A short trip or excursion, usually for pleasure; an outing.

The meaning is that Bloomberg was off having fun somewhere while the city endured a miserable blizzard.

Oh, and among the rest of the synonyms:

- *trip* is the common term that defines some kind of "going out"
- *excursion* is simply a trip of some kind
- *outing* is a trip that is (usually) taken for pleasure
- *journey* is a long trip of some kind; it's defined as any kind of trip, but the implication is that it may be arduous and often discoveries are made along the way

Answer (score 2):

There's another solecism in that *Times* article, Yoichi, which is misuse of the word "secretive." 
It applies essentially to people and not to inanimate objects: the mayor himself may be *secretive*, for example, but the trips he takes out of town are *secret*.

[There's another word that you might like for another kind of trip that a politician takes: *junket*.]

Comment: Thanks Fortunate. It’s precious input. It’s difficult for a foreign English learner like me to discern distinction between secretive (essentially applied to people) and secret (that can modify abstract noun). I’ll be mindful in using them.