# One word for "short trip"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there any one word for "short/small trip/tour"?
Or relatively similar word?

Comment: How about thesaurus?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an alternative word to "journey" for a shorter travelling time?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34839/what-is-an-alternative-word-to-journey-for-a-shorter-travelling-time); related: [What is the difference between “jaunt” and “excursion”, “trip” and “outing”? Can we say “secretive outing” or “secretive absence”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11721/what-is-the-difference-between-jaunt-and-excursion-trip-and-outing-can)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Jaunt* means:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/jaunt)

> A short trip or excursion, usually for pleasure; an outing.

Comment: See also Alfred Bester's _The Stars My Destination_ (_Tyger, Tyger!_ in the UK).